# A php page should be displaying a thumbnail, but instead shows a broken image

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a basic image gallery, and I found a tutorial for how to do so here: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/create_thumbnail_images.php

However, using this code just gets me a broken image on the webpage where the thumbnail should be. The thumbnail does exist, and file permissions are all good, so that's not the issue. I did modify the function a little bit, so I'm wondering if that's the issue.

Here is my modified version of `generate_gallery()`.

```
function generate_gallery($basePath) {
        $pathToThumbs = $basePath . ".thumbs/";
        $output = "<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" width=\"500\">";
        $output .= "<tr>";

        // open the directory
        $dir = opendir($pathToThumbs);

        $counter = 0;
        // loop through the directory
        while (false !== ($fname = readdir($dir))) {
            // strip the . and .. entries out
            if ($fname != '.' && $fname != '..') {
                $output .= "<td valign=\"middle\" align=\"center\"><a href=\"{$basePath}{$fname}\">";
                $output .= "<img src=\"{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}\" border=\"0\" />";
                $output .= "</a></td>";

                $counter += 1;
                if ($counter % 4 == 0) {
                    $output .= "</tr><tr>";
                }
            }
        }
        // close the directory
        closedir($dir);
        $output .= "</tr>";
        $output .= "</table>";
        echo $output;
    }
```

In addition, here is the HTML from the page it generates. (Sorry in advance for the poor formatting. Incidentally, how do I get the PHP to put the HTML on new lines and stuff?) There is a test image of a duck in the folder, so the duck's thumbnail should appear. Instead, all I get is a broken picture.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>20141120.1130</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.php">Back to Index</a><br>250-ducks.png<br><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="500"><tr><td valign="middle" align="center"><a href="/mnt/ddcs_a/AEMP/Screens/20141120.1130/250-ducks.png"><img src="/mnt/ddcs_a/AEMP/Screens/20141120.1130/.thumbs/250-ducks.png" border="0" /></a></td></tr></table>    </body>
```

Comment: That image path looks more like an absolute filesystem path that a web URI.

Comment: Does it need to be a web URI?

Comment: Yep, your browser will currently be making a request to `http://thedomainname.whatever/mnt/ddcs_a/AEMP/Screens/20141120.1130/250-ducks.png` which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: Alright. That did the trick. Thank you very much. I guess that tutorial was a little out of date. If you want to make this the answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below code in your script,

```
$pathToThumbs = $basePath . "/thumbs/";
$output .= "<td valign=\"middle\" align=\"center\"><a href=\"{$fname}\">";
$output .= "<img src=\"{$fname}\" border=\"0\" />";
```

no need to use absolute path.